# Should I create general MQTT topic for all devices?

Tags: mqtt, message, iot

I try to design the topic structure for manage devices in factory
Should I create only one general topic and all devices need subscribe to. With this way, we must do some filter at device code to receive exactly message

Comment: This question has no correct answer, only opinions and as such is off topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Without a lot more details about the system you are trying to build we can't even offer suggestions on what would work in your situation.